# ios LINESTRING parsing

Tags: ios, xcode, json, parsing, dictionary

I have been planning the route as a custom in google maps for iOS.

How do I parsing the incoming JSON in LINESTRING??

My LINESTRING:

```
"coordInfo": "LINESTRING (28.646751729297 40.9993029074749, 28.6470087874434 40.9995465119554, 28.6470087874434 40.9995465119554, 28.6474633603416 41.0000088561426)"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, from what you posted, that objectForKey@"coordInfo" gives you a single string with numbers in parentheses. You could parse that using the NSString method componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: passing a set that contains left and right parentheses, comma, and space to produce an array of the individual number strings (as well as the word "LINESTRING" as the first string in the array). The array will also contain some empty strings where 2 separator characters are together (like comma and space), so you'll have to test for that when taking objects out of the array.

You could also use an NSScanner like this:

```
NSString *toParse = @"LINESTRING (28.646751729297 40.9993029074749, 28.6470087874434 40.9995465119554, 28.6470087874434 40.9995465119554, 28.6474633603416 41.0000088561426)";
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:toParse];
    double num;
    while (! [scanner isAtEnd]) {
      [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:nil];
      [scanner scanDouble:&num];
      // put numbers into an array here or use them somehow
      NSLog(@"%f",num);
    }
```

Comment: Tried your code but it logs the last number twice (probably of the ")" at the end) , adding this in the IF fixed it for me: while (![scanner isAtEnd] && scanner.scanLocation < scanner.string.length - 1)